# flutter download image and save it in asset

Tags: flutter, dart, directory, download, imagedownload

i use package `image_downloader` for download svg image.
i want to save them in asset file project.
can anyone help me please how can I do that ?
`image_downloader: ^0.31.0`

here is my code:

```
  downloadSvg(url, name)async{
    await ImageDownloader.downloadImage(url,
      destination: AndroidDestinationType.custom(directory: 'E:/projects/Myapp/assets/icons')
        ..inExternalFilesDir()
        ..subDirectory("icons/$name.svg"),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible you can't save it to your asset file dynamically to flutter the app at run time.

You need to save that file to the user device or you can use any local storage packages for that. for example, you can use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) , [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage)

One should only use assets to store files which shall remain common for all users.

Comment: actually, I want to download SVG and replace it with a file in my asset. it's not possible?

Comment: No, you can't do any modifications to your asset file. You can save that file to local storage and then access or modify it or you can preCache file.